# в каких случаях в массивах на php в конце ставится запятая а в каких нет? или она ставится всегда?

Tags: php

в каких случаях в массивах на php в конце ставится запятая а в каких нет? или она ставится всегда??

Comment: Некоторые варианты php sniffer (для WordPress Extra, скажем) требуют запятую в конце каждого элемента массива.

Answer (score 4):

Последнюю запятую обычно ставят для удобства, в случае если элементы располагают на отдельных строках. Без запятой, при добавлении нового элемента массива, системы контроля версий зафиксировали бы изменение двух строк (в одной строке появилась запятая, а вторая новая), а не одной. Кроме того добавить новый элемент бывает удобно продублировав предыдущий (в редакторах кода есть специальные сочетания клавиш для дублирования строки). Если элементы массива находятся на одной строке, последнюю запятую обычно не ставят.

```
$arr1 = [
    'foo' => 'Foo',
    'bar' => 'Bar',
];

$arr2 = [1, 2];
```

Answer (score 3):

На ваше усмотрение. Синтаксис позволяет и то, и другое.